# How to declare and implement a const and inline member function?

Tags: c++, methods, function-qualifier

Code:

point3f.h

```
Class Point3f {
     ...
     inline void project2D(ProjType p, const Point2i& view) const;
};
```

point3f.cpp

```
inline void Point3f::project2D(ProjType p, const Point2i& view) const {
    switch(p) {
        case PROJ_XY:
            glVertex2f(x * view.x, y * view.y);
            break;
        case PROJ_YZ:
            glVertex2f(y * view.x, z * view.y);
            break;
        case PROJ_XZ:
            glVertex2f(x * view.x, z * view.y);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Calling this function raises an error in compile time:

```
    undefined reference to `Point3f::project2D(ProjType, Point2i const&) const'
```

I tried every case without and with `inline` symbol:

`inline` in header, not in cpp:

```
 Warning: inline function ‘void Point3f::project2D(ProjType, const Point2i&) const’ used but never defined [enabled by default
 undefined reference to `Point3f::project2D(ProjType, Point2i const&) const'|
```

`inline` in header, also in cpp:

```
 Warning: inline function ‘void Point3f::project2D(ProjType, const Point2i&) const’ used but never defined [enabled by default
 undefined reference to `Point3f::project2D(ProjType, Point2i const&) const'|
```

`inline` not in header, but in cpp:

```
 undefined reference to `Point3f::project2D(ProjType, Point2i const&) const'|
```

`inline` not in header, neither in cpp:

```
 It works but that's not what I want
```

Question:

1. Does `const and inline member function` make sense?
2. How to declare a `const and inline member function`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function being `const` has nothing to do with it. If you want it `inline`, you must define it in the header file instead of in `point3f.cpp`. Example:

```
class Point3f {
    ...
    inline void project2D(ProjType p, const Point2i& view) const
    {
        switch(p) {
        case PROJ_XY:
            glVertex2f(x * view.x, y * view.y);
            break;
        case PROJ_YZ:
            glVertex2f(y * view.x, z * view.y);
            break;
        case PROJ_XZ:
            glVertex2f(x * view.x, z * view.y);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

In this case, the `inline` keyword is not needed at all. If you define the function inside the class definition, `inline` is the default. But you can still specify it, if you want (as I've done in the above example.)

Comment: To clarify, the problem isn't in the mixing of `const` and `inline` (I do it all the time), but in the fact that the `inline` must be in the header file.

Comment: Following what you've said, g++ just raises another warning that `warning: inline function ‘void Point3f::project2D(ProjType, const Point2i&) const’ used but never defined [enabled by default]`

Comment: @ComboZhc Don't put the function in the .cpp file at all. Put it *only* in the header.

Answer (score 1):

Im teste this and work fine!
this example can be viewd at: http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/cplus/c++.rules/chap7.html

Example 24: Overloading an operator/function with respect to const-ness

```
   #include <iostream.h>
   #include <string.h>
   static unsigned const cSize = 1024;
   class InternalData {};

   class Buffer
   {
      public:
         Buffer( char* cp );

         // Inline functions in this class are written compactly so the example
         // may fit on one page. THIS is NOT to be done in practice (See Rule 21).

         // A. non-const member functions: result is an lvalue
         char& operator[]( unsigned index ) { return buffer[index]; }
         InternalData& get() { return data; }

         // B. const member functions: result is not an lvalue
         char operator[]( unsigned index ) const { return buffer[index]; }
         const InternalData& get() const { return data; }

      private:
         char buffer[cSize];
         InternalData data;
   };

   inline Buffer::Buffer( char* cp )
   {
      strncpy( buffer , cp , sizeof( buffer ) );
   }

   main()
   {
      const Buffer cfoo = "peter";// This is a constant buffer
      Buffer foo = "mary";// This buffer can change

      foo[2]='c';// calls char& Buffer::operator[](unsigned)
      cfoo[2] = 'c' // ERROR: cfoo[2] is not an lvalue.

      // cfoo[2] means that Buffer::operator[](unsigned) const is called.

      cout << cfoo[2] << ":" << foo[2] << endl; // OK! Only rvalues are needed

      foo.get() = cfoo.get();
      cfoo.get() = foo.get(); // ERROR: cfoo.get() is not an lvalue
   }
```

hope with help!

peace and light!

Answer (score 0):

You declared it as inline in cpp file, thus no symbol is emitted, in point3f.cpp it's always inlined. But other files which include the header, have no way of inlining the function, they need this symbol to be emitted. I'd guess that's the case here.